# JAVA RMI Based Application Hang (client)

Tags: java, sql-server

Currently I am facing application (JAVA RMI based) hang situation and RMI client GUI become Black.
In the application log does not record any exception and client / server communication has completely stopped at one stage. Once user restart the application it will resume the operations.

Initially we thought it was due to a JVM issue since we saw a dump file during this hang situation. This Dump file was not able to open or copy during this time, it is disappearing once we closed the application. We re-installed the JVM but this issue still hits intermittently.

We noticed this issue started few months after the production cutover and we did not come across during our testing and the initial few months of live cutover.

Application background

-RMI client/server based compiled on java 1.7_55
-OS (client Win7 32 bit & Server Win 2008 32 bit data centre), Win2008 runs on VMWare
-DB MSSql server 2008

It would be great if someone can advice me on this.

Thanks and Regards

Chamantha

Comment: Check the thread-dump